# use an external library in pyspark job in a Spark cluster from google-dataproc

Tags: import, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a spark cluster I created via google dataproc. I want to be able to use the *csv library* from databricks (see https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). So I first tested it like this:

I started a ssh session with the master node of my cluster, then I input:

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
```

Then it launched a pyspark shell in which I input:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('gs:/xxxx/foo.csv')
df.show()
```

And it worked.

My next step is to launch this job from my main machine using the command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster <my-dataproc-cluster> my_job.py
```

But here It does not work and I get an error. I think because I did not gave the `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0` as an argument, but I tried 10 different ways to give it and I did not manage.

My question are:

1. was the databricks csv library installed after I typed `pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0`
2. can I write a line in my `job.py` in order to import it?
3. or what params should I give to my gcloud command to import it or install it?

Comment: There's a bug in Dataproc where JARS are not being picked up for Pyspark jobs. I am looking into an alternative solution. I just wanted to let you know that we're looking at the larger bug and I am seeing if we can ID an interim fix for you as well. :)

Comment: hoping for both a workaround and a fix here too, thx @James!  we're trying to use dataproc with the cassandra connector from both python and scala

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short Answer**

There are quirks in ordering of arguments where `--packages` isn't accepted by `spark-submit` if it comes after the `my_job.py` argument. To workaround this, you can do the following when submitting from Dataproc's CLI:

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster <my-dataproc-cluster> \
    --properties spark.jars.packages=com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 my_job.py
```

Basically, just add `--properties spark.jars.packages=com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0` before the `.py` file in your command.

**Long Answer**

So, this is actually a different issue than the known lack of support for `--jars` in `gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark`; it appears that without Dataproc explicitly recognizing `--packages` as a special `spark-submit`-level flag, it tries to pass it *after* the application arguments so that spark-submit lets the `--packages` fall through as an application argument rather than properly parsing it as a submission-level option. Indeed, in an SSH session, the following does *not* work:

```
# Doesn't work if job.py depends on that package.
spark-submit job.py --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
```

But switching the order of the arguments does work again, even though in the `pyspark` case, both orderings work:

```
# Works with dependencies on that package.
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 job.py
pyspark job.py --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 job.py
```

So even though `spark-submit job.py` is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for everything that previously called `pyspark job.py`, the difference in parse ordering for things like `--packages` means it's not actually a 100% compatible migration. This might be something to follow up with on the Spark side.

Anyhow, fortunately there's a workaround, since `--packages` is just another alias for the Spark property `spark.jars.packages`, and Dataproc's CLI supports properties just fine. So you can just do the following:

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster <my-dataproc-cluster> \
    --properties spark.jars.packages=com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 my_job.py
```

Note that the `--properties` must come *before* the `my_job.py`, otherwise it gets sent as an application argument rather than as a configuration flag. Hope that works for you! Note that the equivalent in an SSH session would be `spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 job.py`.

Comment: This helped me, but I am now struggling to register a new repository in addition to my package. I have tried adding ``--properties spark.jars.packages=org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:2.4.0,spark.jars.ivy=http://conjars.org/repo`` but somehow the two forward slashes get converted into one, and the driver errors out via the below. Do you have any thoughts on this error / the proper way to supply a fully qualified url with two forward slashes: ``Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: basedir must be absolute: http:/conjars.org/repo/local``

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to @Dennis.

Note that if you need to load multiple external packages, you need to specify a custom escape character like so:

```
--properties ^#^spark.jars.packages=org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.10:2.3.2,com.data‌​bricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1
```

Note the ^#^ right before the package list.
See `gcloud topic escaping` for more details.